# Ban users from choosing a common password

Tags: security, passwords

Is it a good idea to ban users from choosing [common passwords](http://www.whatsmypass.com/the-top-500-worst-passwords-of-all-time), it might be overkill for a small site, with a couple of thousand visitors a month... but if you sell a product or service where money exchanges hands, would you consider doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you enforce strong passwords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167917/how-do-you-enforce-strong-passwords)

Comment: Well, they talk about giving a nice message to the user rating their password, I'm suggesting not letting the user create an account if their password is weak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it involves money or personal information you should force the user to have at least 6 characters of a mixture between numbers and letters (many say 8 but I like 6).  You may want to store a table of common quick passwords that people should not use like 123456, etc.

You should also link an expiration date for each password (in my particular case users must change there password every 3 months).  Keep track of previous passwords and warn users that they cannot use the same password (for at least a duration of time).

Answer (score 4):

I think it makes perfect sense to enforce some level of security on passwords.

Instead of banning a list of common passwords you should consider making your users aware of the security issues when they are choosing a weak password, and perhaps even require them to use a mix of different cases, numbers, symbols etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think this website has the answer.
[Passwords don’t have to be Long and Complex](http://www.labnol.org/tech/complex-passwords/14071/)

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is a password strength policy, and is very common with financial institutions and academic websites. My university enforces a minimum of 6 characters, with at least one uppercase, lowercase and non-alphabetical character, for example. Policy compliance can be checked by a simple regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing complex passwords provides virtually no security.  I know this won't be popular but it is.  Here is why; as password requirements got more complex it has become more common for users to use the same password across multiple sites.

Since a password with 2 upper, 2 lower, 2 number, and 2 special characters likely meets the password complexity requirements for most websites it WILL be reused.

Far more effective method to breach a website **especially one that uses email address as username** is to attack another website and then match those emails against your usernames.  Even better  Even better is to offer some "free" service which requires a login (free mp3, free porn, free gift card, etc).

If I make a website and store username & passwords in plaintext the odds are good and increase with number of unique users that we share a user in common (email address) and given enough shared users the likelihood approaches 100% that at least one of those users has re-used the same password.  I know username/password on my site thus I know the username/password on your site.

You should impose some minimum complexity requirements just to avoid common password & dictionary attack but don't burden your users with ultra strong password requirements.  You create a lot of grief for little real security.  Real security is often hard.  **If you want real security you likely need two factor authentication.** My brokerage for example doesn't allow me to choose my own username (which often will be reshared) and requires a RSA token to login, along with my password. Something I have + something I know.

Even better would be 3 factor authentication; adding geolocation of login with further authentication from new/unknown location.